# Is it possible to use 'MethodInvokingFactoryBean' to create a mock bean?

Tags: spring, mockito, factory

We can use `Mockito.mock(SomeCls.class)` to create a mock, but how can we use `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` to define it in application context xml file?

I tried:

```
<bean id="userService" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.mockito.Mockito"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="mock"/>
    <property name="arguments" value="????">
    </property>
</bean>
```

How to pass `my.UserService` as argument to the `mock` method? Is it possible?

Comment: is `my.UserService` name of class or bean ?

Comment: Why would you do that? Have you tries using @Spy and @InjectMocks?

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond: `my.UserService` is the full qualified name of a class

Comment: @AnnaZubenko because I want the mock be injected to other beans automatically. I can't do that with `@Spy`

Comment: Well, @InjectMocks does that, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the `factory-method` approach. Spring will interpret the constructor-arg as a `Class` object.

```
<bean id="userService" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
  <constructor-arg value="fully.qualified.class.name.SomeCls" />
</bean>
```

I haven't tried it, but presume you could do the same with the `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`, by passing the fully qualified class name to the `arguments` property.